# Downloading DotnetCore 1.1 delivers "DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

This is a simple question.

I am advised on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/) page that to upgrade an existing project to asp.net core 1.1 I need to download the .NET Core 1.1 SDK.

I am directed to go to [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current) page to download .NET Core 1.1 SDK. It says .net framework/.net core/ Xamarin. I click on .net core option in the middle.

I then click on option "current" and leave "SDK" as is.

It says at the top .NET Core 1.1 SDK - Installer.

I click on the x64 option for windows and get "DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3". This is not what I was expecting.

So where is the Dotnet 1.1 installer or have they not labelled this correctly? ...or is this the correct file anyway?

Comment: The SDK, Tooling and Runtime versions of .Net Core are a bit confusing. If you download the file you mentioned you will get the Preview 2 tooling for Visual Studio with the current .Net Core SDK which is 1.1. So if you install the MSI everything should work as expected. You will find the SDK in C:\Program Files\dotnet after setup is completed. There you can also add other versions side by side if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That download page is a bit confusing. When you get to the download page you'll see tabs saying **LTS** and **Current**. Click the **Current** tab to get to the 1.1 download. "LTS" stands for 'long term support' and refers to a released version (1.0.*) that Microsoft is going to support for a while.